# How to make sure newly created connectors are straight?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm creating a Visio Flowchart diagram. **I want all connectors by default to be "Straight".** Is there any way to set a default style for newly created connectors? Currently all my connectors are always drawn "Right Angle" initially.

Note that I'd prefer any solution to work for both drawing a connector with the corresponding Tool, and for drawing a connector through the smart interface when hovering a process block.

Things I've tried:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> → Design Ribbon → Layout subribbon → Connectors → Straight. This will not be persisted for new connectors.
- Going through all the options under: Design Ribbon → Variants (the caret for a pullout menu) → Connectors. This is only for the style of connector, it seems.
- Selecting various different Themes. Haven't found one that has Straight connectors by default.
- Opening Page Setup → Layout and Routing. There is in fact an option [Routing → Appearance] there which can be set to "Straight" vs "Curved", but in this dropdown "Straight" actually means "Right Angle".

To put it in a picture, here's what happens now:

[image: drawing a connector giving default Right Angles]

And here's what I *want* to happen:

[image: a straight connector]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like this has been a common question for ages ;). You can change default connector style by editing "Dynamic Connector" master in the document stencil (in your case, set it to be "straight").

To do this:

1. Open the "Shapes" sidebar
2. Hit the flyout icon next to "More Shapes" and select "Show Document Stencil"
3. At the bottom a new panel shows which contains "Dynamic connector": right click it, and under "Edit Master" select "Edit Master Shape"
4. Select the connector on your screen (should be a line with one right angle)
5. Use the ribbon (Design > Layout > Connectors) to set it to "Straight"
6. Close the window top left with the [X], and choose "Update the connector and all of its instances"

New connectors will now default be routed as straight connectors.

Here are some other sources that tell a similar story:

- [Answers.Microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/how-to-set-default-connector-style-in-visio-2010/ce95262a-72bb-46a5-9265-0297af2151a5)
- [Visguy.com](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=1070.0)

Comment: Edit Master is grayed out for me

Comment: Yes it's not work for defaults, only for your own shapes.
If you are bored trying to deal with this like me , you can copy-paste your lines instead.

Comment: In Visio 2013, step 6 has the [X] in the upper right corner.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you very much for this tip!

Answer (score 3):

To make the default connector straight or curved, on the File menu, click Page Setup, click the **Layout and Routing** tab, and then in the Appearance list, click Straight or Curved. New connectors that you add to your drawing will now be straight or curved.

Taken from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-connectors-curved-angled-or-straight-4587d3b3-4552-4361-8d19-f4a2d259d9a8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikolay's answer above, in Visio 2003 I couldn't find the "flyout icon" so I would add the following 2003 specific bits to the steps above:

Step 0. You need to add a dynamic connector to your document before it will show up in the Document Stencil. THEN you can edit it.

Step 1. File > Shapes > Show Document Stencil.

...

Step 5. In 2003 there was no ribbon in the editor, so I had to right click on the arrow and then chose "Straight Connector"

Hope this helps someone else!